Slow Neovim startup, but only sometimes and not a specific plugin
Sometimes, Neovim takes a relatively long time to start up. But then subsequent openings (even of the same file) are very fast. Because it's so unpredictable, I find it hard to reproduce. It could be once every 10 minutes, maybe once an hour. It's usually after some period of not using Neovim (or files I typically open with Neovim).
I read this post and it sounds exactly like my situation but with one crucial difference: for me, there is not one specific line item on --startuptime that is the cause... it's nearly every line item.
Comparing a slow startup and a fast startup, it would seem that after a certain point, nearly every line item takes 10x longer than the fast startup.
To make it even more confusing, I use my configuration on two different laptops (one personal, one work), and it only occurs on my work laptop (which leads me to believe it's something else put on my work laptop). Both laptops are MacBook Pros (one M1, one M3). Both running MacOS 15.1.
If you have any insight into what could cause this or any additional tips on how to investigate further, I would greatly appreciate it!
The slow startup
The fast startup

Vim starts slower at work, and I think it has to do with a corporate security scanner, but I’ve never confirmed it…

@D.BenKnoble Your comment got me thinking and I went through all the settings on my work laptop. Finally realized disabling allowing Microsoft Defender to work in the background solved this problem. Ridiculous but true. Thanks!

Does anybody want to post an answer?

@JeffErickson can take credit for this one ;)

Based on @D.BenKnoble's comment, I looked into the corporate security software on the laptop. After disabling Microsoft Defender's ability to run in the background (System Settings -> General -> Login Items and Extensions -> Allow in the background), the problem is resolved.
